# Simple excel macro

Tags: excel, vba, colors

I have just started to work on Excel macros.
Please let me know what is wrong in the following code:

```
Sub color_red()

Dim range As range

For R = 1 To 20
    If Cells(R, 1).Value = 1 Then range(R, R).Interior.ColorIndex = 3
Next R

End Sub
```

Error message displayed:

> Object variable or with block variable not set

Thanks in advance for your guidance.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use variable name which is any VBA: key word, function, object name, collection name, etc. Try to change your variable name from `range` into `rngTable`.

**EDIT after additional information** written as comments in different areas of that post:

change your `if` code line into:

```
If Cells(R,1).Value = 1 Then Cells(R,1).EntireRow.Interior.ColorIndex =3
```

which will colour all sheet columns in row `R`. To colour certain range, e.g. in 10 columns you could use this line instead of your `if`:

```
If Cells(R,1).Value = 1 Then Cells(R,1).Resize(1,10).Interior.ColorIndex =3
```

Comment: thanks for your response...!! I changed the name of the variable but getting the same error :(

Comment: please put your `if` line in comment here or add(!) improved code in the question. I want to check what you did with `range(R,R)` which could not be `rngTable(R,R)`

Comment: Sub color_red()
Dim rngTable As range
 
For R = 1 To 20
If Cells(R, 1).Value = 1 Then rngTable("R:R").Interior.ColorIndex = 3

                                   
Next R
 
End Sub

Answer (score 1):

I see that you are still having problem with this code. Please try this simple subroutine, this might be what you need:

```
Public Sub ColorRowIf()
    Dim r As Long
    For r = 1 To 20
        If Cells(r, 1).value = 1 Then
           Cells(r, 1).EntireRow.Interior.ColorIndex = 3
        End If
    Next r
End Sub
```

Please also note that using **'Cells()'** is not a good way to go, but I have included it for simplicity (as asked). **'Cells()'** will always refer to the active sheet cells which might not always be the case. So, instead you should use full reference of the sheet (by code name method) -- so in this example it should say for e.g.:  **Sheet1.Cells(r,1).Value = 1**. Also, remember **Sheet1** is not the tab name, its the code name that you see in project window.

Comment: Thanks mate...!!! it works as i wanted. Like u said i will go with the sheet name instead of cells.

Comment: My pleasure :) if you are satisfied with any answer please mark it as complete. thanks

Answer (score 0):

@KazJaw is correct, you cannot use a key word as a variable name. But the `range` or `rngTable` variable is still used before it is set.

You could still use a `Range` variable, but why don't you use the same way of addressing as in the if statement?

```
If Cells(r, 1).Value = 1 Then Cells(r, 1).Interior.ColorIndex = 3
```

Otherwise you would have to set the range object before you use it:

```
Set rngTable = Cells(r, 1)
```

Comment: Thanks kazjaw ...!!! IF a cell for eg. A1 is = 1, then i want to colour the entire row that is the first row. This what i am trying. As i am beginner can you please let me know where i am wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I feel like a lot of people gleaned over the fact your variable 'R' is not defined other than 666bytes.

Declaring the variables you are going to be using is an important thing to do in order to get code to work.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of range you can use the Cells function. You have to refer the WorkSheet for using range. Since nothing is mentioned ,its throwing Object variable or with block variable not set.

```
Sub color_red()
Dim r As Integer

For r = 1 To 20
If Cells(r, 1).Value = 1 Then Cells(r, r).Interior.ColorIndex = 3
Next r
```

End Sub